# How many ways are there to make $35¢$ change with these specific coins?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many ways are there to make $35¢$ change with:
a) $1952$ pennies, $1959$ pennies, and $1964$ nickels? (Numbers refer to the years of the coins, not the quantity.)
b) $1952$ pennies, $1959$ pennies, $1964$ nickels, and $1971$ quarters?

For those not used to American currency, all types of pennies are worth $1¢$, all types of nickels are worth $5¢$, and all types of quarters are worth $25¢$

I haven't got the slightest idea of how to solve this, but I know that it is using distributions.

Comment: It would help if you define the value of a 1952 penny and 1959 penny and all the coins denominations, since all the people here wouldn't know about it.

Comment: Okay, I added the denominations

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For (a), consider cases depending on the number of nickels.  Let $x_1$ be the number of $1952$ pennies; let $x_2$ be the number of $1959$ pennies.  If there are $n$ nickels, then you have to solve the equation $x_1 + x_2 = 35 - 5n$, in the non-negative integers.

Answer (score 0):

The standard generating function argument is that 2 types of values that are worth 1 unit and 1 type of values that are worth 5 units are counted by
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2(1-x^5)}=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+\cdots + 148x^{35}+\cdots
$$
argues that 148 changes for type a) are possible. See https://oeis.org/A008732 for more values.

For 2 types of pennies, one type of nickels and 1 type of quarters we have
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2(1-x^5)(1-x^{25})} = 1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\cdots + 166 x^{35}+\cdots
$$
we have 166 variants for b).